# Any good java libraries for capturing job statistics?

Tags: java, hadoop, bigdata

We're building a product which runs multiple parallel jobs on big data. Any suggestions for a good java library which can help us measure  / encapsulate the per-job and aggregate statistics - like time / memory / resource usage?

Further, any good java library which integrates well with frameworks like hadoop / hbase / yarn etc. to capture framework specific statistics related to particular jobs ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Cloudera admin interfaces:

[Cloudera admin interfaces](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CM4Ent/4.5.4/Cloudera-Manager-Enterprise-Edition-User-Guide/cmeeug_topic_3_1.html)